# Why compiler error does not happen when variable be placed in class element

Tags: java

thanks for reading ,here's the code:

```
public class ClassA{

}
class ClassB{


    public String getValue()
    {
        ClassC classC;
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^    
        return classC.getValue();

    }
}

class ClassC{
String value;
    public String getValue()
    {
     value="test";
            return value;

    }
}
```

this will cause IDE respond "classC might not been initialized" in compile time.
But when I move this line : "ClassC classC;" to outside of the getVlalue() function in classB , IDE become quiet and throws runtime error instead.

Can anyone help to explain the reason? 
many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's because when `Classc classC;` is moved to outside the `getValue()` function it becomes a field of whatever class it's in.  Java will initialize all unset fields automatically. In this case, since it's an object, it will be initialized to `null`.  I assume the runtime error you get is a `NullPointerException`?

When it is declared inside a method it is not automatically initialized, you have to explicitly set it to something.  Since you didn't do that before using it, the compiler complained.

Comment: thanks for help.. it is NullPointerException that's righ :)

Answer (score 1):

Because when `ClassC classC;` moves just inside the Class and not a variable inside the function , it becomes an instance variable, and by default all instance variables are initialized when the instance of the class (read - object) is instantiated (by `null` if no value is provided , primitive types by their own different values , like int by `0`, etc) .

Additionally , the `classC` variable's value can be set by other methods in the same class (including constructor) , and if its public, it's value can be set from outside the class as well.

Hence according to compiler, `classC` can be initialized before access , hence it does not complain .

Comment: so it's the different between instance and function variable cause it ... many thanks.

Comment: Yes, function variables are not initialized automatically with `null` , but instance variables are initialized with null automatically when object is created.